# Pandas Regex Extract to New Column If Condition

Tags: python, pandas, regex, python-3.10

I am trying to run a script that will look at the value in a cell along a specific column ("Name") and check to see if it contains a particular string. If the cell contains the string, the script will look at the value contained in the "Value" cell and either copy the value into the "New_Value" column and append a string or regex extract a portion of the value and append a string into the new column.

The issue is with the regex extraction of the phone numbers. If I remove the regex portion, the script will copy the cell value into the New_Value cell, with the appended [PHONE] string. When I include the regex extraction, it doesn't copy anything over, like it didn't see a match to the regex. The weird thing is that if I alter the code so the regex just returns a True/False based on a Match, it returns a True for a match.

Am I somehow screwing up regex extraction? Any help is appreciated, thank you.

My code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import re

df = pd.read_csv("path_to_file")

df.loc[df["Name"].str.contains("Number"), "New_Value"] = (
    df["Value"].str.extract(r"(\d{10,13})") + "[PHONE]"
)
df.loc[df["Name"].str.contains("Animal"), "New_Value"] = (
    df["Value"] + "[PET]"
)
df.loc[df["Name"].str.contains("Company"), "New_Value"] = (
    df["Value"] + "[COMPANY]"
)
df.loc[df["Name"].str.contains("Contact"), "New_Value"] = (
    df["Value"] + "[NAME]"
)
```

Sample Data

```
| Name     | Value             |
| -------- | ---------------   |
| Number   | +639892943187     |
| Company  | Ebert_LLC         |
| Animal   | Snake             |
| Contact  | Michal_Ashburner  |
| Number   | 668949201578      |
| Company  | Hoppe_LLC         |
| Animal   | European_badger   |
| Contact  | Marlee_Gofford    |
```

Desired result

```
| Name     | Value             | New_Value              |
| -------- | ---------------   | ----------------------
| Number   | +639892943187     | 639892943187[PHONE]    |
| Company  | Ebert_LLC         | Ebert_LLC[COMPANY]     |
| Animal   | Snake             | Snake[PET]             |
| Contact  | Michal_Ashburner  | Michal_Ashburner[NAME] |
| Number   | 668949201578      | 668949201578[PHONE]    |
| Company  | Hoppe_LLC         | Hoppe_LLC[COMPANY]     |
| Animal   | European_badger   | European_badger[PET    |
| Contact  | Marlee_Gofford    | Marlee_Gofford[NAME]   |
```

Comment: Your name column simply lacks the value `Phone`. Either change that in the data, or in your code by replacing `Phone` with `Number`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, that was a typo when I was building the question. I corrected the typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the job:

```
df.loc[df.Name == 'Number', 'New_Value'] = df.Value.replace('+', '', regex=False) + '[PHONE]'
df.loc[df.Name == 'Animal', 'New_Value'] = df.Value + '[PET]'
df.loc[df.Name == 'Company', 'New_Value'] = df.Value + '[COMPANY]'
df.loc[df.Name == 'Contact', 'New_Value'] = df.Value + '[NAME]'
```

Note that the `.loc()` can be utilised to create new columns/rows in a DataFrame.

Comment: This did work, thank you. I'm still a bit confused why the `str.extract()` didn't work when it would successfully match the regex. Any thoughts? Thanks again for this solution.

Comment: Crap, just found some values that don't match the sample completely. Some of the "Number" values don't have the "+". Is there a way to adjust this solution to have it extract at the first digit?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with `str.extract()` and regex patterns but `str.replace('+', '')` should do the trick – see adjusted answer.

Comment: Thanks, it gets the job done. Appreciate you taking the time to help me out.